# Adjoint momentum Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, dirac-equation

So we have the commonly quoted momentum space version of the Dirac equation and the adjoint Dirac equation:

$$
(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)u=0
$$
Often, we are asked to show that the adjoint momentum Dirac equation can be written as:
$$
\bar{u}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)=0
$$
I'm not too sure on the method. However, I have attempted something.

I multiply the top equation by $\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}\times$ and the bottom equation by $\times\gamma^{\nu}u$ giving:

$$
\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)u=0
$$

$$
\bar{u}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)\gamma^{\nu}u=0
$$
Taking the sum of these two gave me:
$$
\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}u-\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}mu+\bar{u}\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}u-\bar{u}m\gamma^{\nu}u=0
$$
I then use $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}=-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}$, giving me:
$$
\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}u-\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}mu-\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}u+\bar{u}\gamma^{\nu}mu=0
$$
And which point I can say that it is true. I'm just wondering if this is sufficient or if there is another more correct way of getting the adjoint Dirac equation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$
(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)u=0
$$

Using the property $\overline{AB}=\bar{B}\bar {A}$, we have the following:
$$
0=\overline{(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)u}=\bar u \overline{(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)}
$$

Now, use $\overline{A+B}=\bar A+\bar B$:
$$
0=\bar u (\overline{\gamma^\mu p_\mu}-\bar m)
$$

Next, as both $m$ and $p_\mu$ are real numbers, we have $\bar m=m$ and $\bar p_\mu=p_\mu$:
$$
0=\bar u (\overline{\gamma^\mu} p_\mu- m)
$$

Finally, use the fact that the gamma matrices are self-adjoint, that is, $\bar \gamma^\mu=\gamma^\mu$:
$$
0=\bar u (\gamma^\mu p_\mu- m)
$$
and we are done.

Your attempt cannot work because you are trying to prove the adjoint equation by using the adjoint equation, which means that your argument is cyclical.